# How do you add GPUImage to an iOS project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gpuimage

I am trying to make a camera/photo app that will add a filter on an image. I have heard of Brad Larson's GPUImage and so I downloaded it and tried to manipulate it to be more familiar with the code.

Now, I made a new project in Xcode and added it on my frameworks, but i don't have any idea how to use it on a new project.

How can I properly use GPUImage in my new project?

Comment: I've added  detailed steps w/ pictures here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21896243/1553014 see if it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know how I could be much clearer than the step-by-step instructions I put on [the very first page of the GitHub project](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and in the README.md under the section "Adding the framework to your iOS project":

> Once you have the latest source code for the framework, it's fairly
>   straightforward to add it to your application. Start by dragging the
>   GPUImage.xcodeproj file into your application's Xcode project to embed
>   the framework in your project. Next, go to your application's target
>   and add GPUImage as a Target Dependency. Finally, you'll want to drag
>   the libGPUImage.a library from the GPUImage framework's Products
>   folder to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase in your
>   application's target.
>
> GPUImage needs a few other frameworks to be linked into your
>   application, so you'll need to add the following as linked libraries
>   in your application target:
>
> - CoreMedia
> - CoreVideo
> - OpenGLES
> - AVFoundation
> - QuartzCore
>
> You'll also need to find the framework headers, so within your
>   project's build settings set the Header Search Paths to the relative
>   path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the
>   GPUImage source directory. Make this header search path recursive.
>
> To use the GPUImage classes within your application, simply include
>   the core framework header using the following:
>
> ```
> #import "GPUImage.h"
> ```
>
> As a note: if you run into the error "Unknown class GPUImageView in
>   Interface Builder" or the like when trying to build an interface with
>   Interface Builder, you may need to add -ObjC to your Other Linker
>   Flags in your project's build settings.
>
> Also, if you need to deploy this to iOS 4.x, it appears that the
>   current version of Xcode (4.3) requires that you weak-link the Core
>   Video framework in your final application or you see crashes with the
>   message "Symbol not found: _CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate" when you
>   create an archive for upload to the App Store or for ad hoc
>   distribution. To do this, go to your project's Build Phases tab,
>   expand the Link Binary With Libraries group, and find
>   CoreVideo.framework in the list. Change the setting for it in the far
>   right of the list from Required to Optional.
>
> Additionally, this is an ARC-enabled framework, so if you want to use
>   this within a manual reference counted application targeting iOS 4.x,
>   you'll need to add -fobjc-arc to your Other Linker Flags as well.

To see this in action, look at any of the many sample applications I ship with the framework.

Comment: i'm a little confused with this "so within your project's build settings set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the GPUImage source directory. Make this header search path recursive."

Comment: I'm having these errors "'GPUImage.h' file not found" and "Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 Error"

Comment: I've fixed the LLVM issue but GPUImage.h is still not read by my project.

Comment: @LakanBahande - See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10405139/19679 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260291/installing-core-plot-in-xcode-4-2-for-ios-project/10261140#10261140

Comment: Sir! Thank you! i have managed to use it now! but i have another issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722880/gpuimage-gpuimagetonecurvefilter-not-working

Comment: Does the crash with "Symbol not found: _CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate" message occur in archiving time? not runtime?

Comment: @KyokookHwang - It occurs at runtime, but only if you've built for archival or for distribution on the App Store. I also believe that only occurs with specific versions of Xcode.

Comment: @BradLarson Somehow I missed this: " Finally, you'll want to drag the libGPUImage.a library from the GPUImage framework's Products folder to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase in your application's target.
"

Comment: You oughta make a pod file for it imo.

Comment: @BradLarson is it possible make filters like instagram by GPUImage?

Answer (score 5):

Please read this page http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework and this: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Note: Simply, you can copy all source code files in framework/source folder to your project, and import GPUImage.h to use.

Regards!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it in **Swift 5** in **Xcode** for **iOS** with Visual Directions:

Two things before you begin.

- you should start this process on a **copy/duplicate** of your project until you get it correct (it took me several tries), or even start with a new project. If something goes wrong you want to keep your original project intact
- if you have a project open with the GPUImage in it that you are trying to copy, make sure to close it first. You will get an error saying that there is a project with it already open

[image]

1- go to the GPUImage [gitHub page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage3)

2- in the upper right hand corner, click the green `Code` button and then click `Download Zip`

[image]

3- in your current Xcode project (the one that you want to use GPUImage) click the first folder underneath the blue project icon

[image]

4- after that go to the top of Xcode and click `File` > `Add Files to "yourProject"`

[image]

5- when the new window appears go to `Downloads` (or wherever you downloaded GPUImage in the second step) > `GPUImage3-master` > `framework` > `GPUImage.xcodeproj` and then click `Add`. It's important that you make sure `Copy Items if Needed` and `Create groups` are checked.

[image]

6- you will now see `GPUImage.xcodeproj` inside your Xcode project underneath that same folder from step 3 (no need to do anything with it)

[image]

7- click your **main** project's `blue project icon` > `Build Phases` and the middle/center pane should be on `TARGETS`. Make sure you **DON'T** click the GPUImage.xcodeproj, that is the **WRONG** folder

[image]

8- while still under Build Phases click `Dependencies` then click the `plus sign`

[image]

9- when the pop up appears select `GPUImage_iOS` then select `Add` (make you sure you pick the **iOS** version and not the macOS version)

[image]

10- you will now see the `GPUImage_iOS` dependency under `Dependencies` (no need to do anything here)

[image]

11 -now while still under under `Build Phases` click `Link Binary` with Libraries then click the `plus sign`

[image]

12- when the pop up appears under *Workspace* > *GPUImage* > select `GPUImage.framework from 'GPUImage_iOS' target ...` then press `Add` (make sure you select the `iOS` version and not the macOS version)

[image]

13- now the library is linked (no need to do anything here)

[image]

14(a)- This is important, if underneath Build Phases there isn't a **Copy Files**  folder than go to the top of Xcode and select `Editor` > `Add Build Phase` > `Add Copy Files Build Phase`. If the folder is already there **I'm not sure what to do if the folder already exists**. The *Copy Files* folder wasn’t initially there for me and I had create it using step 14(b). I would **assume** if it’s already there just open it and continue to **step 16**

[image]

14(b)- if for some reason `Add Copy Files Build Phase` is **grayed out**, [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28446747/4833705) or under `Build Phases`, in the upper left hand corner press the `plus sign`, then select `New Copy Files Phase`

[image]

15- now you will see a brand new `Copy Files` directory underneath Build Phases

[image]

16- if `Copy Files` isn't already open, press the toggle button to open it and next to `Destination` change `Resources` to `Framework`

[image]

17- while still under `Copy Files`, press the `plus sign`, when the pop up appears, if this is an **iOS** project, under `Products`, select the **top** `GPUImage.framework` and press Add. This last step is under Brad's directions

> Add a new Copy Files build phase, set its destination to Frameworks,
> and add the **upper GPUImage.framework (for iOS)** or lower
> GPUImage.framework (for Mac) to that

[image]

18- now the `GPUImage.framework` has just been added to `Copy Files`

[image]

19- your Build Phase screen should look like this

[image]

20- clean the project `Shift+Command+K`

21- in whatever file you intend on using the GPUImage in go to the top and enter `import GPUImage` (it should start to appear under autocomplete) then build your project.

[image]

22- test to see if a Class and a Method from GPUImage works inside your project

```
// nothing is supposed to actually happen here, just test to see if the SmoothToonFilter() class and filterWithOperation() method are recognized without any errors
let testImage = UIImage(named:"some_image_from_your_assets")!
let toonFilter = SmoothToonFilter()
let _ = testImage.filterWithOperation(toonFilter)
```

[image]

Done!

Comment: Way better than the accepted answer. Thanks for the effort for creating this visual guide.

Comment: @mkeremkeskin when I found the accepted answer I was lost. It took me several hours to figure out how to actually do it. The accepted answer makes it seem like 1-2-3 which I’m sure it is for someone who did something similar before.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest of all ways of integrating GPUImage into your project is via [cocopods](/questions/tagged/cocopods). And while the GPUImage CocoaPods repo isn't actually maintained by Brad, it's upkeep is pretty regular, and it makes integration a breeze.

## [`>` Go get it](http://cocoapods.org/pods/GPUImage)