# GPUImage: GPUImageToneCurveFilter Not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I have managed to use the GPUImage in my app now and tried putting filters in my photos on button click, but there another issue.

```
    GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter;
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
    } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageThresholdEdgeDetection alloc] init];
    } else if (sender.tag == 3) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc] init];
    } else if (sender.tag == 4) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"crossprocess.acv"];
    } else if (sender.tag == 5) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"Summer.acv"];
    } else if (sender.tag == 6) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"NightCat.acv"];
    } else if (sender.tag == 7) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"Breeze.acv"];
    } else if (sender.tag == 8) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"OldTone.acv"];
    } else if (sender.tag == 9) {
        selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToneCurveFilter alloc] initWithACV:@"Sky.acv"];         
    }
    filteredImg = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:image];
    [insertPhoto1 setImage:filteredImg];
```

GPUImageToneCurveFilter is not working, whenever i clicked a button with .acv filter it crashes the app and throws this error.

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

With highlight on this part

```
version = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(*(int*)([databuffer bytes]));
```

What should i do? What does the error mean?

Answer (score 0):

seems you have a memory managment issue here with casting your variables.
You use two pointer signs.
It seems to me wrong.

```
version = CFSwapInt16BigToHost((int*)([databuffer bytes]));
```

or better

```
version = CFSwapInt16BigToHost([databuffer bytes]);
```

Make sure the arg and return values matches the function according to the manual!

in the apple manual this is stated about this function:

```
CFSwapInt16HostToBig
```

Converts a 16-bit integer from the host’s native byte order to big-endian format.

```
uint16_t CFSwapInt16HostToBig (
   uint16_t arg
);
```

**Parameters**
**arg**
The integer whose bytes should be swapped.
**Return Value**
The integer with its bytes swapped. If the host is big-endian, this function returns arg unchanged.